# Summing numbers in a file

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
aaa 15
aaa 12
bbb 131
bbb 12
ccc 123
ddddd 1
ddddd 2
ddddd 3
```

I would like to get a sum for each unique element in the left side like this and also calculate how many of each element are summed up:

```
aaa 27 - 2
bbb 143 - 2
ccc 123 - 1
ddddd 6 - 3
```

How would I accomplish this with AWK or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in `awk` by collecting the sums into two arrays, using column 1 as the key to both arrays (then pipe to `sort` if desired):

```
awk '{sums[$1] += $2; counts[$1] += 1}
     END {for (key in sums) {print key, sums[key], "-", counts[key]}}' file | sort
```

Output:

```
aaa 27 - 2
bbb 143 - 2
ccc 123 - 1
ddddd 6 - 3
```